# Firestore How to structure data for intersection

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

How can data be structured in Firestore to search for the intersection of elements?  For example:

- Kit 1 contains: a, b, c
- Kit 2 contains: d, e, f
- Kit 3 contains: d, e, h
- Kit 4 contains: r, f, x

Using the application the person selects that they have kit 1 and 2, it should return kit 3. If they select kit 1 and 3, it would be useful to show that buying kit 4 would mean they have kit 2.

This example is tiny compared to the total data set. There are many thousands of kits and millions of parts.

I think the way to structure this data is to have a lot of overlap between them.  There should be 2 top level collections, one for kits and one for parts. The kit collection will contain documents for each kit which includes a map of parts where each part has an id and a quantity.  The parts collection will contain documents for parts. Each part will have an id that matches the id in the kit document maps and contain an array of kit ids.

The application will read the kits, which returns potentially thousands of parts, then it will read each of those parts and get all the kit numbers, then it will read all of those kits and see which ones it has all the parts for.  This will probably work, but as the database grows this will read thousands of documents per search.  Is there a better way to store the data to reduce the number of documents but still scale?